# Horizontal scrolling not working in Chrome with Sharkoon Draconia mouse

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

I have recently upgraded to a Sharkoon Draconia gaming mouse from a standard Logitech mouse.  Previously by tilting the scroll wheel left or right I was able to scroll horizontally in Chrome with my previous Logitech mouse, however this feature no longer works with the new Draconia mouse.  I have bound the tilting of the scroll wheel to horizontal scrolling in the drivers and it does work in applications like Microsoft Word.

[image: Draconia Drivers Software]

Why is Chrome not detecting horizontal scrolling from my mouse and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Chrome but with your particular mouse. The default Tilt Left/Right buttons do not send valid HID messages.

To get around this, I suggest installing [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

With your mouse utility, remap the Tilt Left/Right buttons to say the Scroll Lock key and Pause key.

Then create an AutoHotkey script. e.g. tilt.ahk . Fill it with the following;

```
#NoTrayIcon
ScrollLock::Click WL
Pause::Click WR
```

Save it and compile. Add a shortcut of the executable it created to your Startup folder or registry.

Works a treat at my end.